# Return a string in a try block

Tags: java, return, try-catch

I'm new to programming in general and have to create an IP scanner in Java for my course and I have currently hit a brick wall. After some help from a friend I have been able to take an IP address from a jFrame and convert it into an IP number. From there I have it passed into a public String which scans the addresses. It will currently cycle through the addresses with no problem, however I have no idea how to take the result out of the try block to be displayed in a text block, like you would expect an IP scanner to do. Here is my code:

```
private void jBtnPSScanActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:


        //Get text from text boxes
        String pingSSIP1 = jTxtPSSIPOne.getText();
        String pingSSIP2 = jTxtPSSIPTwo.getText();
        String pingSSIP3 = jTxtPSSIPThree.getText();
        String pingSSIP4 = jTxtPSSIPFour.getText();
        String pingSEIP1 = jTxtPSEIPOne.getText();
        String pingSEIP2 = jTxtPSEIPTwo.getText();
        String pingSEIP3 = jTxtPSEIPThree.getText();
        String pingSEIP4 = jTxtPSEIPFour.getText();

        //Convert text into IP Numbers      
        long ipNumberS = 0;
        ipNumberS = ipNumberS + (Long.parseLong(pingSSIP1)*256*256*256) ;
        ipNumberS = ipNumberS + (Long.parseLong(pingSSIP2)*256*256) ;
        ipNumberS = ipNumberS + (Long.parseLong(pingSSIP3)*256) ;
        ipNumberS = ipNumberS + (Long.parseLong(pingSSIP4)) ;
        System.out.println (ipNumberS);
        long ipNumberE = 0;
        ipNumberE = ipNumberE + (Long.parseLong(pingSEIP1)*256*256*256) ;
        ipNumberE = ipNumberE + (Long.parseLong(pingSEIP2)*256*256) ;
        ipNumberE = ipNumberE + (Long.parseLong(pingSEIP3)*256) ;
        ipNumberE = ipNumberE + (Long.parseLong(pingSEIP4)) ;
        System.out.println (ipNumberE);


        String startAddress = Long.toString(ipNumberS);
        String endAddress = Long.toString(ipNumberE);

        String returnIP = pingSweep(startAddress, endAddress, ipNumberS, ipNumberE);

        System.out.println(returnIP);

        //Update jTxtBlock with returnIP and result

    }
```

And:

```
public String pingSweep (String startAddress, String endAddress, long ipNumberS, long ipNumberE) 
{
    String ip = "";


    for (long currIP = ipNumberS; currIP < ipNumberE; currIP++)
    {
        try {
            ip = Long.toString(currIP) ;
            System.out.println(currIP);
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            System.out.println("Host Reachable? " + host.isReachable(4000));
            System.out.println(currIP);
            System.out.println(ip);
            ip = ip + " " + currIP + " " + host.isReachable(4000);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
            break;
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
            break;
        }

    }
    return ip;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Matthew

Comment: What is the type of `jTxtBlock`? Is it `JTextArea`? This isn't supposed to be a guessing game.

Comment: Well I'm so sorry that a newbie to code and to this forum includes his validation in the code he copies and pastes. At least I'm showing you what I am looking at, someone may be able to assist me in looking into something a little different if I am wrong. All I need is a little help. Bully someone else.

Comment: @MatthewCurtis The FAQ **is for newbies**.

Comment: @MatthewCurtis he's not bullying you, he's curtly pointing out that when you ask for help or some kind of favor (in _any_ forum, not just SO), you are taking someone's time for your own gain, and in that situation you have a social obligation to minimize the effort of your would-be helper to the greatest extent possible. By failing to minimize your code of anything you know is unhelpful towards solving the problem, you are not only failing your obligation but you are wasting other people's time. This will not endear people into helping you.

Comment: +1 Well put, @mah... it's all about give-and-take, and since there's no money involved, it must be of the social kind.

Comment: I appreciate it being give and take, but why bother being the first one to comment and leaving such a negative view? I have been hitting my head on the desk about this problem for the last 3 weeks, searching everywhere on the Internet, yet all I can find is random code snippets which mean little to nothing to me. I'm not the kind of person who can look at code and go 'Oh yeah, that line of code is wrong'. I know others can, which is why I asked here. I was expecting some help from people who know what they are talking about, not to be pointed to another FAQ. jTxtBlock is a JTextArea.

Comment: @MatthewCurtis The SO FAQ doesn't help you solve your coding problem; it helps you ask a question that will attract a good answer.

Comment: Now, apparently `JTextArea` has a method `append(String)`. Did you try to use it and failed?

Answer (score 1):

So this is what is what you have. a String that you want to display on your JFrame? is it ?

You could add a label on your JFrame and pass your string to that label

refer [How to Label](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for details

PS : using label is just a suggestion to display read only text, if you want to use inputText,textArea or whatever its upto your like and requirement

**UPDATE**

OP confirms he is using a TextArea

HINT :  jTextArea.append(host.isRechable) method to append the new values to jTextArea as your ping receives response.

Comment: No, I wish to take the result of the host.isReachable and display it in a Text Area on the original form, ie, when the user presses jBtnPSScanActionPerformed. Currently the System.out.println() only displays the final result, not every individual result of each ping. I wish every result to be displayed in the text area as it is found.

Comment: @MatthewCurtis it is a TextArea. that really doesnt matter much. So what you actually want to do is, when the button is pressed, display ping(s) in the textArea?

Comment: Exactly @Mukul Goel, it needs to perform a ping sweep to determine which addresses are in use on the network. For example: 192.168.0.1 - Success
192.168.0.2 - Fail
192.168.0.3 - Success
192.168.0.4 - Success
192.168.0.5 - Fail
192.168.0.6 - Fail
...ect.
My try stores the final result which can be displayed without great difficulty, however I need every result, whether fail or pass and it needs to be viewed in the Text Area, appended as the result is found.

Comment: @MatthewCurtis, try using `jTextArea.append(host.isRechable)` method to append the new values to jTextArea